# How to compile with make but also include all dependencies

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm compiling a C++ program on linux, and I can run make and it all compiles, but when I need to downgrade or change one of it's dependencies for another program, it breaks. I was wondering if it was possible to create a standalone executable, with dependencies bundled inside? There's not many dependencies, so size isn't an issue.

Comment: We have no idea what you mean.

Comment: When I run make, it generates an executable, but when I change or downgrade one of it's dependencies, the executable breaks. I was wondering if I could generate an executable that didn't have any dependencies, they would be bundled with the executable.

Comment: By "dependencies" what you do mean?  That's a pretty generic term.

Comment: Sytem packages such as libssl, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you're asking is, can you link with static versions of libraries (which are included in the program directly) instead of dynamic versions of libraris (shared libraries) which are kept external to your program.

The answer is "yes", but it's not always straightforward.  First you have to ensure you actually have the static versions of the libraries installed in your system: the static and dynamic libraries are different files and often the "standard" installation provides only the dynamic library.

If you're already compiling code against those libraries you probably already have the static libraries installed because, at least on GNU/Linux systems, the static libraries are often included in the "dev" packages along with the header files etc. needed to compile code.

To make this work you need to modify your linker command line.  If you have a sufficiently new version of the binutils package (which provides the linker), you can change your link line to replace arguments like *-lssl -lcrypto* with arguments like *-l:libssl.a -l:libcrypto.a* (don't forget the colon after the -l) and that should do it.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing with this program but if you're distributing it to anyone else be sure you're familiar with, and following, the licensing for any libraries you're using.